# ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED what to check?

Tags: domain-name-system

On my ubuntu server I host a few websites (vps at digitalocean).
For some reason on all domainnaims on that server I get an

```
 ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED
```

error message

I havent changed anything today and everything worked for a few months so far. When I type the ip adres of my server I get a webpage (so the content still exist). The domainnames I have are at a different company, some point to another webserver and they still work. The domainnames (with the error) still point to

```
 ns1   ns1.digitalocean.com
 ns2   ns2.digitalocean.com
 ns3   ns3.digitalocean.com
```

What can I check to find the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Digitalocean's name servers are down:
see https://status.digitalocean.com/

Comment: Well, you could swap name servers - but that usually takes somewhere between 24-48 hours, so probably you are just best for the Digitalocean team to resolve this.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant to say that "you are probably just best to leave it for the Digitalocean team to resolve this".